# The statement: 'I go to France every year'; is this present progressive?

Tags: present-continuous, past-simple

Am I right in assuming 'I go to France every year' is present progressive?

As opposed to: 'I went to France last week' I assume is past simple tense.

Comment: Google solves fast, on hold now.

Answer (score 1):

*I go* is what folks call the 'simple' present—or 'present simple' if you're feeling elegant. The progressive present (or present progressive) is constructed with a present-tense form of auxiliary *be* and the *-ing* form of the lexical verb: *I am going*.

PRESENTS:
* SIMPLE: I go to France every year.
* PROGRESSIVE: I am going to France this week. —*which is usually not a description, as you might think, of your current activity but of your planned **future** activity.*

PASTS
* SIMPLE PAST: I went to France last year.
* PROGRESSIVE PAST: I was going to France last year.

FUTURIVES (*None of them is 'simple', and I hesitate to call them 'future'*) —these get wonky:

- I will go to France next year.

  *But you cannot cast this in the progressive, because* will *no longer has an* -ing *form; that's now a wholly owned subsidiary of the adjective class. Instead you have to use a periphrastic modal, which is constructed with a tensed form of* be + going + to + *the infinitive form of your lexical verb—in this case,* go:
- I am going to be going to France next year.

  And just to make sure you don't get complacent:
- I am to go to France next year.  *and even*
- I go to France next year.

Answer (score 0):

Your first example is the simple present.

Your second example is the simple past.

The progressive is a modification that can apply to past, present or future that is often used to stress the duration of an action, often to place an event within its time-frame.  You create the progressive by using some form of "to be" before the verb and "ing" at the end of the verb.

For instance...

> I am going to France this year.

Comment: Is someone able to tell me what the correct tense is, so i can read up on them both? Was the past simple one correct at least?